# Error in updating table fields when posting values through ajax

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, jquery

I m trying to update profile of student through ajax the script is runing good i get all the values passed in dataString but it is not updating the values of fields when the savebasic.php is called through ajax.

Jscript:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".savestudent").click(function() {

    var _firstname=$("#firstname").html();
    var _lastname=$("#lastname").html();
    var _gender=$("#gender").html();
    var _location=$("#location").html();
    var _aboutme=$("#about").html();
    var _dob=$("#dob").html(); 

    var dataString= 'fname='+ _firstname + '&lname='+ _lastname + '&gender='+ _gender + '&location='+ _location + '&about='+ _aboutme + '&dob='+ _dob ;
    alert(dataString);

    $.ajax
    ({

    type: "POST",
    url: "savebasic.php",
    data: dataString,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {

        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(html)
    {


    }
    });
    });
});

</script>
```

savebasic.php:

```
<?php

include_once('controller/profile.controller.php');
$profileObject=new ProfileController();

        $fname=$_POST['fname'];
        $lname=$_POST['lname'];
        $gender='M';
        $loc=$_POST['location'];
        $about=$_POST['about'];
        $birth=$_POST['dob'];   

$upt=$profileObject->updateUserprofile('59',$fname,$lname,$birth,$gender,$loc,$about);

?>
```

if i directly pass values on savebasic.php it works . but while passing through ajax it does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

You are using data field in ajax in a wrong way. You should do:

```
data:{'fname=': _firstname, 'lname=':_lastname,'gender=':_gender,'location=': _location}
```

Answer (score 0):

your data string is set up like a GET - normal syntax would be:

```
data: {'fname': _firstname, 'lname':_lastname .... }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Change your code to assign data in following way


<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".savestudent").click(function() {

    var _firstname=$("#firstname").html();
    var _lastname=$("#lastname").html();
    var _gender=$("#gender").html();
    var _location=$("#location").html();
    var _aboutme=$("#about").html();
    var _dob=$("#dob").html(); 

    var data= {     fname:_firstname,
                    lname:_lastname,
                    gender=: _gender ,
                    location:_location,
                    about: _aboutme,
                    dob: _dob};
    alert(data);

    $.ajax
    ({

    type: "POST",
    url: "savebasic.php",
    data: data,
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {

        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(html)
    {


    }
    });
    });
});

</script>
```

Also, it is not correct way to get the value from the element..
If the firstname, lastname and other fields are in text boxes, then you should access those like this.

```
var _firstname=$("#firstname").val();
```

Or if they are in span or div tag, then access those like this

```
var _firstname=$("#firstname").text();
```

Answer (score 0):

your data part is wrong . also you forgot to mention the `dataType`
I have edited your code .

check it out :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/
ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$(".savestudent").click(function() {

    var _firstname=$("#firstname").html();
    var _lastname=$("#lastname").html();
    var _gender=$("#gender").html();
    var _location=$("#location").html();
    var _aboutme=$("#about").html();
    var _dob=$("#dob").html(); 

   // var dataString= 'fname='+ _firstname + '&lname='+ _lastname + '&gender='+ _gender + //'&location='+ _location + '&about='+ _aboutme + '&dob='+ _dob ;
   // alert(dataString);

    $.ajax
    ({

    type: "POST",
    contentType: 'text/html',
dataType: 'text',
    url: "savebasic.php",
    data: {
      fname: _firstname, lname :_lastname, gender :_gender, location : _location 
      ,about : _aboutme , dob : _dob
    },
    cache: false,
    success: function(html)
    {

        alert('success');
    },
    error: function(html)
    {


    }
    });
    });
});

</script>
```

this will give you 100% correct result .